# JPA Criteria query sum with Spring Data Pageable

Tags: java, spring, jpa, criteria, spring-data-jpa

I have a method in repository:

```java
public Long sumOfPrices(Specification<Order> spec) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> query = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<Order> root = query.from(Order.class);
    query.select(builder.sum(root.get(Order_.price)));
    query.where(spec.toPredicate(root, query, builder));
    return sum = em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}
```

How to write a method with pageable?

```java
public Long sumOfPrices(Specification<Order> spec, Pageable pageable)
```

I don't know where to call setMaxResult and setFirstResult, because sum returns a single result.

Comment: http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/ might help

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following:

```
public Page<Long> sumOfPrices(Specification<Order> spec, Pageable pageable) {
    // Your Query
    ...

    // Here you have to count the total size of the result
    int totalRows = query.getResultList().size();

    // Paging you don't want to access all entities of a given query but rather only a page of them      
    // (e.g. page 1 by a page size of 10). Right now this is addressed with two integers that limit 
    // the query appropriately. (http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa)
    query.setFirstResult(pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize());
    query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

    Page<Long> page = new PageImpl<Long>(query.getResultList(), pageable, totalRows);
    return page;
}
```

That is how we do it, I hope it's help.

Further information can be found on: http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: You need to add `TypedQuery<Long>typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);` before `int totalRows = ...`. I ran this method. `typedQuery.getResultList().size();` always return 1, because called `query.select(builder.sum(root.get(Order_.price)));`.

Comment: you ask for a pageable process, that the query (sum) makes no sense, i was aware but i thing you change it in your code. But so I do not confuse other people do I change it.

Comment: It works when used query.select(root.get(Order_.price)), but query.select(builder.sum(root.get(Order_.price))) returns a single result. So setMaxResults works not as I need.

Comment: This is me aware! But i thought you want the pageable for an other scenario. The whole pageable doesn't make sence with only one result.

Comment: Take care with int totalRows = query.getResultList().size(); you are calling again getResultList() below and this make the application slower